# C# Razor Pages Uploadin Files to Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I have written an app that should also copy files to Azure Cloud. It works in my development environment, but when I deploy the app to Azure Cloud and launch it from there, it can't access the files on the executing machine to upload them. What can I do, what am I doing wrong?

```
public ActionResult Index(string fileName)
{
    string myIP = GetIP();
    string folderPath = @"\\" + myIP + @"\c$\SWAP\";
    string containerName = "fileupload";
    string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";     var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xlsx");
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

   foreach (var file in files)
   {
        var filePathOverCloud = file.Replace(folderPath, string.Empty);
        var path = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "_" + filePathOverCloud;                 try
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file));
            containerClient.UploadBlob(filePathOverCloud, stream);                 
        } catch {
            ViewData["Message"] = "File not found ...";
            return View();
        }
    }
        return View();
}
```

**OK rickvdbosch, I tried like this, but <*IFormFile FileName*> always returns NULL ... what am I doing wrong?**

`````
````HTML-Page
<div class="text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4">File Upload</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Upload File</label>
        <span>Select File:</span>
        <input type="file" accept=".xlsx" name="FileName" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

````PageController    
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IFormFile FileName)
{
  string containerName = "fileupload";
  string connectionString = "DefaultEndpoint...fix=core.windows.net";

  if (FileName != null)
  {
     //do upload
  } 
  else
  {
     //throw error
  }
  return View();
}
`````

Comment: Why do you think Azure can access your machine's hidden C drive share? If Azure could, the entire internet could.

Answer (score 0):

A web application should never, under any circumstance, have access to the filesystem of the client visiting the web app without the user explicitly pointing to files or a location where to get them. Never ever.

Your application needs to be adjusted so that it asks the user which files to upload, and process that information on the post of the page (meaning the user explicitly gave permission to upload the selected file(s)).

Please have a look at [Uploading Files in Razor Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload)

> For the most part, you will use forms to capture data from the user as simple string, numeric, datetime or boolean values. Forms can also be used to upload files. Successful file uploading has three basic requirements:
>
> 1. The form must use the `post` method
> 2. The form must have an `enctype` attribute set to `multipart/form-data`
> 3. The uploaded file must map to an `IFormFile` data type

Comment: Thanks for the information, that's the point I missed, as I thought I was taking all *.xlsx files from a specified directory. The app is only used by a specified group of users.